# preg_match_all not ignoring characters after pattern

Tags: php, regex

If my string is

```
<?php $str = 'hello world!'; function func_hello($str) { echo $str; }
```

I want to find the name of any functions in the string

I'm using the code

```
preg_match_all('%func_.* ?\(%', $c, $matches);
```

This is a basic example of what I'm doing. In the real world I'm getting results like this

```
func_check_error($ajax_action_check, array(
func_post('folder') == '/' || func_post(
func_check_error($fvar_ajax_action_check, array(
```

Whereas I want the result to be

```
func_check_error(
func_post(
func_check_error(
```

I've tried `\b` to set a boundary but it's not working. i.e.

```
preg_match_all('%\bfunc_.* ?\(\b%', $c, $matches);
```

Comment: Do you see the space in your pattern? It should instead be [`func_.*?\(`](https://regex101.com/r/tfd9nY/1/) Additionally, parsing/analyzing code with regular expressions might lead to unexpected results.

Comment: The space is because there could be a space between the function name and brackets, so the question mark is to make it optional

Comment: Something like `func_.*? ?\(` stops the `.*` taking too much.

Comment: What is the actual input string? What is the value of `$c`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.*` capture the opening parenthesis, and then the first parenthesis (after the function name) is captured, because there is the following parenthesis (the one of the array) which correspond to the `\(` of your pattern.

You should try a more restrictive condition on the function name, such as alphanumeric only or anything but a parenthesis, maybe replace the `func_.*` by `func_[^(]*` wich will stop at the first parenthesis match

Comment: `func_[^(]` just returns the first character, eg `func_c`

Comment: I forgot to put `*`, the `[^(]` is here to replace the `.`

Answer (score 0):

Simple regex should work fine:

```
~func_.*\(~
```

If this is not giving the results you expect, it may be due to another issue with your code and how you're using the regex.